# Webcam Intel Realsense not working on Fedora

Tags: linux, drivers, intel, camera

My laptop carries an Intel RealSense F200 webcam that isn't working properly on Fedora, when I start the webcam the output image is green with my silhouette.
I searched the net and found this library https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense but since the installation guide is specific for Ubuntu I'm at a loss.

There is a script (patch-uvcvideo-fc23.sh) that install some dependencies and load the uvcvideo module. But even after that the webcam is still green.
The output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` is

```
332.078253] Hardware name: LENOVO 80NV/Allsparks 5A, BIOS CDCN35WW 03/29/2016
[  332.078259]  0000000000000286 0000000015ae496a ffff88006cc27bc0 ffffffff813dbcff
[  332.078266]  ffff88006cc27c10 0000000000000000 ffff88006cc27c00 ffffffff810a740b
[  332.078274]  0000050300000246 ffff88006cc27d88 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[  332.078282] Call Trace:
[  332.078296]  [<ffffffff813dbcff>] dump_stack+0x63/0x84
[  332.078302]  [<ffffffff810a740b>] __warn+0xcb/0xf0
[  332.078309]  [<ffffffff810a748f>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
[  332.078320]  [<ffffffffc119186c>] ? uvc_ioctl_enum_fmt+0x9c/0xb0 [uvcvideo]
[  332.078334]  [<ffffffffc06597d4>] v4l_enum_fmt+0xe24/0x1190 [videodev]
[  332.078346]  [<ffffffffc065a3a1>] __video_do_ioctl+0x291/0x310 [videodev]
[  332.078351]  [<ffffffff81269f14>] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
[  332.078358]  [<ffffffff81258026>] ? path_openat+0x376/0x15b0
[  332.078384]  [<ffffffffc0659e60>] video_usercopy+0x320/0x5b0 [videodev]
[  332.078400]  [<ffffffffc065a110>] ? video_ioctl2+0x20/0x20 [videodev]
[  332.078411]  [<ffffffff8125a4a5>] ? do_filp_open+0xa5/0x100
[  332.078430]  [<ffffffffc065a105>] video_ioctl2+0x15/0x20 [videodev]
[  332.078446]  [<ffffffffc06556ac>] v4l2_ioctl+0xdc/0xf0 [videodev]
[  332.078455]  [<ffffffff8125d4a3>] do_vfs_ioctl+0xa3/0x5d0
[  332.078464]  [<ffffffff8125da49>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[  332.078476]  [<ffffffff817dd3f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1a/0xa4
[  332.078482] ---[ end trace 84debfce61a27ff0 ]---
[  332.078496] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  332.078540] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1961 at drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-ioctl.c:1283 v4l_enum_fmt+0xe24/0x1190 [videodev]
[  332.078544] Unknown pixelformat 0x00000000
[  332.078547] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm fuse arc4 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast ip6t_rpfilter ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_conntrack ip_set nfnetlink ebtable_nat ebtable_broute bridge ip6table_security ip6table_raw ip6table_nat nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_nat_ipv6 ip6table_mangle iptable_security iptable_raw iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack iptable_mangle ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables nvidia(POE) bnep bbswitch(OE) vfat fat snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_codec ath10k_pci coretemp kvm_intel kvm uvcvideo ath10k_core snd_hda_core snd_hwdep videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_seq videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core mac80211 videodev
[  332.078622]  snd_seq_device media snd_pcm btusb irqbypass hci_uart btrtl crct10dif_pclmul ath snd_timer crc32_pclmul btbcm btqca cfg80211 snd btintel ghash_clmulni_intel bluetooth soundcore i2c_i801 mei_me ideapad_laptop joydev mei sparse_keymap rfkill pinctrl_sunrisepoint shpchp pinctrl_intel intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss tpm_crb tpm_tis acpi_pad tpm nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) i915 8021q i2c_algo_bit crc32c_intel garp drm_kms_helper stp llc mrp sdhci_pci sdhci drm r8169 serio_raw mmc_core mii wmi video i2c_hid fjes [last unloaded: nvidia]
[  332.078710] CPU: 1 PID: 1961 Comm: AudioThread Tainted: P        W  OE   4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64 #1
[  332.078714] Hardware name: LENOVO 80NV/Allsparks 5A, BIOS CDCN35WW 03/29/2016
[  332.078717]  0000000000000286 0000000015ae496a ffff88006cc27bc0 ffffffff813dbcff
[  332.078722]  ffff88006cc27c10 0000000000000000 ffff88006cc27c00 ffffffff810a740b
[  332.078727]  0000050300000246 ffff88006cc27d88 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[  332.078733] Call Trace:
[  332.078745]  [<ffffffff813dbcff>] dump_stack+0x63/0x84
[  332.078754]  [<ffffffff810a740b>] __warn+0xcb/0xf0
[  332.078763]  [<ffffffff810a748f>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
[  332.078777]  [<ffffffffc119186c>] ? uvc_ioctl_enum_fmt+0x9c/0xb0 [uvcvideo]
[  332.078797]  [<ffffffffc06597d4>] v4l_enum_fmt+0xe24/0x1190 [videodev]
[  332.078817]  [<ffffffffc065a3a1>] __video_do_ioctl+0x291/0x310 [videodev]
[  332.078826]  [<ffffffff81269f14>] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
[  332.078834]  [<ffffffff81258026>] ? path_openat+0x376/0x15b0
[  332.078851]  [<ffffffffc0659e60>] video_usercopy+0x320/0x5b0 [videodev]
[  332.078868]  [<ffffffffc065a110>] ? video_ioctl2+0x20/0x20 [videodev]
[  332.078877]  [<ffffffff8125a4a5>] ? do_filp_open+0xa5/0x100
[  332.078895]  [<ffffffffc065a105>] video_ioctl2+0x15/0x20 [videodev]
[  332.078909]  [<ffffffffc06556ac>] v4l2_ioctl+0xdc/0xf0 [videodev]
[  332.078918]  [<ffffffff8125d4a3>] do_vfs_ioctl+0xa3/0x5d0
[  332.078926]  [<ffffffff8125da49>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[  332.078934]  [<ffffffff817dd3f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1a/0xa4
```

Is there a way to make the webcam working on this system?

Comment: As a side note I'd like to add that on Linux Mint the webcam works out of the box (from Live DVD)

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but maybe this helps somebody.
Fedora 25 also needs the following in order to proper compile:

`dnf install numactl-devel pesign`

The patch for videodev2.h fails. Open the file realsense-camera-formats.path, remove from the line 152 to the end of the file, add the following and save the file:

```
diff --git a/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h b/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h
index a0e87d1..7e00be4 100644
--- a/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h
+++ b/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h
629a630,647
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_Y8I      v4l2_fourcc('Y', '8', 'I', ' ') /* Greyscale 8-bit L/R interleaved */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_Y12I     v4l2_fourcc('Y', '1', '2', 'I') /* Greyscale 12-bit L/R interleaved */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_Z16      v4l2_fourcc('Z', '1', '6', ' ') /* Depth data 16-bit */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_Y8       v4l2_fourcc('Y', '8', ' ', ' ') /* Greyscale 8-bit */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_Y10      v4l2_fourcc('Y', '1', '0', ' ') /* Greyscale 10-bit */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_Y12      v4l2_fourcc('Y', '1', '2', ' ') /* Greyscale 12-bit */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_Y16      v4l2_fourcc('Y', '1', '6', ' ') /* Greyscale 16-bit */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_RAW8     v4l2_fourcc('R', 'A', 'W', '8') /* Raw data 8-bit */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_RW16     v4l2_fourcc('R', 'W', '1', '6') /* Raw data 16-bit */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_INVZ     v4l2_fourcc('I', 'N', 'V', 'Z') /* 16 Depth */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_INZI     v4l2_fourcc('I', 'N', 'Z', 'I') /* 24 Depth/IR 16:8 */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_INVR     v4l2_fourcc('I', 'N', 'V', 'R') /* 16 Depth */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_INRI     v4l2_fourcc('I', 'N', 'R', 'I') /* 24 Depth/IR 16:8 */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_INVI     v4l2_fourcc('I', 'N', 'V', 'I') /* 8 IR */
> #define V4L2_PIX_FMT_RELI     v4l2_fourcc('R', 'E', 'L', 'I') /* 8 IR alternating on off illumination */
> 
> 
>
```

Now go to the librealsense folder and run `scripts/patch-uvcvideo-fc23.sh` (do not run the script while inside the scripts folder, go to the previous directory).

You do not need to run the script as root, it will use sudo as necessary (your user will need to use sudo). Now it should compile. Cheese still showing green for me, but xawtv works.